# implementation of a shell in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, fork, pipe

im trying to implement a shell in C.

What i did so far: i have an array of pointers pointing at all the commands inputed by the user
for example:

```
args[0]: sort
args[1]: <
args[2]: txtFile
args[3]: |
args[4]: grep
args[5]: key
```

then  i set flags every time i find '<', '>', '>>', or '|'. then i used those flags to either redirect, indirect, append or pipe those commands according to how they are being used.

My question is, when processing commands such as:

```
SHELL$: sort < txtFile | grep key
```

should i create multiple processes every time i find a '<', '>', '>>', or '|'? or should i create those processes after i have processed all of the commands?
Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is the code that i have so far:

```
else if(pid > 0) 
{ 
    /* parent process */
    if(!async) 
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    else 
        printf("this is an async call\n");

    if(PIPE_FLAG)
    {
        pid2 = fork();
        if( pid2 == 0)
        {
            waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);   
            close(c2p[1]);
            if(dup2(c2p[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1){
                perror("dup2() failed");
                exit(-1);
            }
            execvp(nxt_args[0], nxt_args);
            perror("exec failed 2. ");          
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if( pid2 > 0)
        {
            close(c2p[0]);
            close(c2p[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            /* error occurred */
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

my first child deals with the sort < txtFile, and then it sends the output of that to a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Don't start any processes til after you've broken up the command line into discrete commands and/or redirections.  Otherwise you can cause issues if the command line was malformed.

As an example, say you have a `destroy_files` that trashes files and optionally says which ones it trashed, and a `fix_files` that fixes them.  Say the user strung these commands together like `destroy_files -v | fix_files < >`.  The shell would do well to say "hey, syntax error here" and not run anything...but if you run commands as you encounter delimiters, too bad for the user.  You've already started the process that destroys their files.)

As for the redirection, you don't need a separate process just to handle redirection.  Simply set up FDs 0, 1, and/or 2 appropriately, and the OS will handle the byte shuffling (blocking or buffering as needed).  All you have to do is wait for the processes to end.

Comment: ok so i should definitely create w.e process i need after processing the entire command arguments.

Comment: what i did was that my child1 executes the first part of the command before the pipe, then parent creates another process, and my child2 runs the remaining commands after the pipe.
Now i noticed that it works, but after it runs the command it hangs there and i press enter and it works again... any idea of why this might be happening?

Comment: @user2913269: Wild speculation here, cause you haven't provided any code... but it sounds like one of the processes manages to get a hold of the real stdin for a bit.  Which hints that maybe you're doing things in the wrong order.  I'd look into the relative order in which you fork, redirect, exec, forward input, close streams/pipes, wait, and/or clean up.

Comment: i added a part of my code... when i create another process the program hangs there... and then if i use another command it runs it, and then it shows the prompt again

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your example:

```
sort < txtFile | grep key
```

You must create a process for `sort`, change its standard input to read `txtFile`, change its standard output to the write part of a pipe and then execute the program `sort`.

You must also create a second process for `grep` than will use the read part of the pipe and execute the program `grep`.

So you need 2 processes. But in order to set the stdout of the first process, you need to parse the pipe.

**Edit:**

First, you create the pipe. You must fork a first time to create a first process and you set stdin and stdout properly for the first process (redirection and write part of the pipe). Then you fork a second time the father to create a second process and you change the stdin to the read part of the pipe. You `exec` in the children to execute `sort` and `grep` after setting the standard I/O.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Maxime, so where should i create the second process? should i create it in the running child, or in the parent of my first process? 
i.e:     
    else if(pid > 0)
    create the new process here

Comment: @user2913269 both processes are children of your shell. The second process is not a child of the first one. Try this on bash: `cat | less` and use `ps -ef` to see it by yourself.

Comment: so in other words the second should be a process of the parent? @maxime

Comment: @user2913269 Your shell must create 2 sub-processes. Both the first and the second processes are children of your shell. You must fork twice.

Comment: so i could fork the same pid twice? im sorry, but i cant seem to visualize what you're trying to tell me. Could you provide some pseudo-code to see what you mean?

Comment: Yes. First, you create the pipe. You must fork a first time to create a first process and you set `stdin` and `stdout` properly for the first process (redirection and write part of the pipe). Then you fork a second time the father to create a second process and you change the `stdin` to the read part of the pipe. You exec in the children to execute `sort` and `grep` after setting the standard I/O.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41054/discussion-between-user2913269-and-maxime)

Answer (score 0):

When creating the processes, you have to set the filedescriptors accordingly. It doesn't make sense to start lots of processes, just to realize that the commandline is screwed up, because forking a process is expensive.

So first parse the parameters, then you will know how how many processes you will need and how to setup the file descriptors of each and then you can run them.

So in your example you will need two processes, one pipe and one redirect.

Comment: okay perfect. so i should first in the creation of the new process i should run the sort, then dup2 the output to a pipe, then in the parent i should create another process, and in that process i should run the grep command correct?

Comment: First you parse everything, if that is ok create the pipes, then you create the processes and connect them with the pipes. The OS should handle the rest, because when the process wants to read or write from the pipes it will block if the next process is not ready. Not sure on that, but it might be a good idea to create the processes in reverse order, because each successive prozess will read (and therefore block) from the previous one).